# Web scraping - extract data from a page using python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

This is the code I am using. it returns an empty list. Could nt figure out what I am doing wrong!

```
from urllib request import urlopen
import re

url = 'http://pubs.acs.org/doi/full/10.1021/jacs.6b10998'# example of a web page
html = urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8')# decoding

cite_year='<span class="citation_year">(.+?)</span>'# extract citation year
pattern = re.compile(cite_year) #compile
citation_year = re.findall(pattern, html) #store data into a variable

print(citation_year)# and print
```

Comment: Are you sure your regex is correct?

Comment: Suggest replacing your first two lines with sample data (I did  html = """<span class="citation_year">test</span>
...
... <span class="citation_year">bar</span>
... <span class="citation_year">three</span><span class="citation_year">four</span>
...
... <span foo>bar</span>"""
and then the rest of your code worked as expected... this would allow you to triage where the issue is and whether your data has quotes like you expect etc.  Also note that SO tends to discourage parsing HTML with regexp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add header to the request, I use `requests` and `bs4` library:

```
import requests
import bs4
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
url = 'http://pubs.acs.org/doi/full/10.1021/jacs.6b10998'# example of a web page
html = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')
year = soup.find(class_="citation_year").text
print(year)
```